# Same python virtualenviroment different OS

Tags: python, windows, macos, virtualenv

if this is not consider a valid question or problem to solve, I can try in other category.

I used to work with python virtualenvs stored on OneDrive and run the projects from different PCs. Now I have to work from Mac OS and virtual enviroments don't seem to be equals.

Is there a way to accomplish this from both OS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean they don't seem to be equals?

Comment: I mean If I create a virtual environment from Windows is not the same in Mac OS. Even if I activate my Windows created virtuales from Mac it dosnt find my installed modules from pip.